# How can i wait until a thread finish its process?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use

```
threading.Thread(target=ftp1.ftptester, args=[self.finallist], daemon=False).start()
```

for processing a list of files it may take upto 3 mins to finish ftptester function the code comes below only have to execute after finishing the thread I have tried

```
kl=threading.Thread(target=ftp1.ftptester, args=[self.finallist], daemon=False).start()

kl.join()
```

But it was giving me error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Note * the thread is called from asyncio ->eventloop-> run_until_complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have called the start at the end and start returns a none type you have essentailly cleared your kl variable. this should fix it.

```
kl=threading.Thread(target=ftp1.ftptester, args=[self.finallist], daemon=False)
k1.start()

kl.join()
```